# single line assignment in javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
(function(){
  var a = b = 3;
})();

document.writeln("a undefined? " + (typeof a === 'undefined'));
document.writeln('<br/>')
document.writeln("b undefined? " + (typeof b === 'undefined'));
```

another interesting thing with javascript, can some body please let me help in understand here what happen.

a and b both should be defined. but i am wrong

Comment: Here only scope of variables a and b causes the problem... Otherwise it will work.
Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/f0mrrnqe/1/

Comment: feeling embarrassed for overlooking :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `a` becomes local variable as it is defined as `var a` but `b` is global(*under the context of window if executed in browser*) as it is not declared using `var` hence outside of the `function` scope, it is `undefined`

If you remove `var` from that statement then both the variables will become `global`

Refer this example:

```js
(function() {
  a = b = 3;
  var c = 3,
    d = 4;
})();

document.writeln("a undefined? " + (typeof a === 'undefined'));
document.writeln('<br/>')
document.writeln("b undefined? " + (typeof b === 'undefined'));
document.writeln('<br/>')
document.writeln("b undefined? " + (typeof c === 'undefined'));
document.writeln('<br/>')
document.writeln("b undefined? " + (typeof d === 'undefined'));
```

Answer (score 4):

`b` is defined because you never declared `b`, so it assumed that it is referring to `window.b`.

`a` is not defined because it is only defined inside the anonymous function.

If you change your code to

```
(function(){
    var a, b;
    a = b = 3;
})();
```

Then you can clearly see both `a` and `b` are not defined outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

a is undefined because you define it inside the function. Therefore the variable scope is limited to the function body.

b is defined because you didn't define it with 'var', which means it is implicitly assigned to the global scope, which means you can see it outside the function body.